# /home on 2 separate hard drives

Tags: linux, partition, system-installation

I use my laptop for work and for personal (eg gaming). I need to keep the two separate, which I currently do with two users. I'm currently running Linux Mint 17.2 64-bit (Cinnamon edition), and would like to keep this OS (I have no problem with reinstalling).

I have recently added an SSD. I'd like to keep everything work-related on the SSD, so that at work, I don't even need to spin up the HDD, but I'd rather not have to reboot. So what I want to do is to have user profiles on the SSD, except for one user profile which should reside entirely on the HDD.

Does anybody have any experience with this? I (think I) know how to do this, but before I start, can anybody provide any advice or suggest obscure pitfalls to avoid?

**Further detail**

Currently, my system looks like this: (info copied from parted, mount points added by me)

```
Model: ATA WDC WD5000BPVT-2 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 500GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system  Flags  Mount
 1      1049kB  21.0GB  21.0GB  primary   ext4         boot   /
 2      21.0GB  500GB   479GB   extended
 5      21.0GB  500GB   479GB   logical   ext4                /home

Model: ATA KINGSTON SNV425S (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 64.0GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start  End  Size  Type  File system  Flags  Mount
```

The SSD is not currently mounted, indeed, there are no partitions created on it at all yet. As requested, here is the output of `mount`:

```
/dev/sda1 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (rw)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
none on /run/user type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=104857600,mode=0755)
none on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw)
/dev/sda5 on /home type ext4 (rw)
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
systemd on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,none,name=systemd)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=cosmo)
```

I want my system to look something like this:

```
Model: ATA WDC WD5000BPVT-2 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 500GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system  Flags  Mount
 1      1049kB  21.0GB  21.0GB  primary   ext4         boot   /
 2      21.0GB  500GB   479GB   extended
 5      21.0GB  500GB   479GB   logical   ext4                /home/gaming

Model: ATA KINGSTON SNV425S (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 64.0GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system  Flags  Mount
 1      1049kB  21.0GB  21.0GB  primary   ext4         boot   /
 2      21.0GB  64.0GB  43.0GB  primary   ext4                /home
```

If nobody suggests anything by the weekend, I'll give it a go and post my results here.

Comment: Are you aware about symbolic links and mount points? Where is the SSD mounted, by the way?

Comment: Please, enter the command `mount` on your laptop (while SSD is on) and report results [in the question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/229657/edit). Also add which namely operating system (not just “linux”) do you use there.

Comment: Done. I understand symbolic links and mount points. I'm not sure if symlinks would be preferable to mount points though? I don't think you can symlink an entire user area..?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing intrinsically special about `/home`. You could just as easily set all your user accounts (except one) to be based from `/work`. (IIRC SunOS used to use `/export/home`, for example, to accommodate its NFS file sharing scheme.)

Anyway, back to your scenario. If the machine has multiple work accounts, I think the way I would approach this is to change the default home directory base from `/home` to `/work`, if necessary moving existing accounts there too (and obviously updating `/etc/passwd` appropriately).

I would temporarily move my home account there, too, and then arrange for the HDD to mount as `/home`. I'd then move my home account back to `/home/roaima` (or whatever works in your situation), again remembering to update `/etc/passwd` appropriately.

Thus, a system that can run without the HDD and has its user accounts under `/work`. Connect the HDD and allow it to mount, then you can log in as your home user account.

The missing part to this is probably something like the automounter, `autofs`. This can be configured to mount the HDD as `/home` on demand, and to dismount it again automatically after it's no longer being used.